# Strip a particular word from the beginning of string in jq output

Tags: shell, jq

I am getting list of values as below using the curl command:

```
curl -s http://internal.registry.com/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[0:5] | to_entries | map( .value )[]'
```

Output:

```
centos
containersol/consul-server
containersol/mesos-agent
containersol/mesos-master
cybs/address-api
```

I want to make sure that output should not have the prefix `cybs/` in it. for example, `cybs/address-api` should just be `address-api`

Comment: Just FYI: `to_entries | map(.value)[]` is equivalent to `.[]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`sub`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)):

```
curl ... | jq -r '.repositories[0:5][] | sub("^cybs/"; "")'
```

Also note that `to_entries | map( .value )` is a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) and should be removed.

Output:

```
centos
containersol/consul-server
containersol/mesos-agent
containersol/mesos-master
address-api
```

Comment: Ironically, `map(f)[]` is also a noop: this expands to `[.[] | f][]`, which can be simplified as `.[] | f`.

Comment: @SantiagoLapresta hehe, thanks for clarifying! I updated the answer :-)